# How to fill an unknown sized vector using iterators?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iterator

I'm trying to create a graph in which I don't know its size , the user fill the vector until user wants.
and how can I get the elements using iterators?

my code which is not completed :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

void main(void)
{
    {
        using namespace std;
        
        vector<vector<char>> graph;
        vector<vector<char>>::iterator outerMove;
        vector<char>::iterator innerMover;
        cout << "enter your verteces name one by one and write done when you are done";
        for (outerMove = graph.begin(); outerMove != graph.end(); ++outerMove)
        {
            //first get the size of vector , how much user wants enters 
        }
        for (innerMover = )
        {
            //now here graph.push_back(innerMove) 
        }
}
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you intend to be the value of the inner vectors, characters like `a`, `b`, `c` or numbers in range [0;256] or [-128;127]? In the latter case, you should explicitly specify if signed or unsigned, as `char` being one or the other is implementation defined!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use iterators in this case, you use [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) and let the vector do its job (that is, resize automatically):

```
vector<std::string> graph;
std::string outermove;  // a proper "list of chars"!

while ((cin >> outermove) && outermove != "done")
    graph.push_back(outermove);
```

Unrelated to the question:

`void main()` is illegal in C++, `main` needs to return `int`. `(void)` is a C way of writing an empty parameter list - in C++ it's simply `()`.

Comment: I this case you are filling strings inside the vector but I want to fill the first vector and then for each of elements in first vector I want to get input.

Comment: You only have one vector, so I'm not sure what you mean by "first vector". Anyway, a string is an iterable container, too. You can walk it, character by character, just like you (I assume) wanted to do with `list<char>`. You can use a `vector<char>`, too.

Comment: @ShahroozLeon Fine by me :) The code I wrote does what *you* wanted to do with *your* code, only correctly, got it? It's not my job to come up with the specification for your work. Must be the language barrier, I'm sure you didn't want to be rude :)

Comment: @jrok , thank you very much , I am never rude with new people which I don't know them , I really appreciate for the time you spent , your work gave me an idea and it was useful for me, but I still don't know how to design a graph which its size is dynamic and work with it, I was just hoping you could also tell me how to make the vector's size dynamic and getting its size from the user.

Comment: It's ok, I'm not native speaker either.  We're fine. Just be more specific - how do you name the vertices, example of valid input, how do you want the contents of vector to look like when you're done, stuff like that.

Comment: For your future information, "Got it?" is perceived as rude in English, so you might want to avoid that in the future!

Comment: @jork , this is what I'm trying to make  check the post again please.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica , thanks for that , I thought if I say do you understand is rude , then what else can I say if none of these?

Comment: @ShahroozLeon I'd go with "Hope that makes sense" or just leave it off ;)

Comment: To be precise: `(void)` is less common, but fully legal in C++ as well, and some people (I assume with C background...) even prefer it...